# How to upload a file using PUT method in REST API?

Tags: html, post, file-upload, slim, put

I need to upload a file and some parametrers to modify an object in the database using PUT method.
But it seems like multipart/form-data in PUT at SLIM.

I already did it with POST, sending both file and parameters to create a new object in the db.

How can i do the same idea of ssending all but with PUT? What's the good way to do it? Without changing to POST (cause i need to modify, not create)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

A file upload via PUT is possible, but not recommended (and not supported by Slim). If you still want to upload via PUT you may implement a custom Middleware that converts the PUT stream into a PSR-7 request object.

Read more: [PHP PUT method support](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php)